# Matrix Scaling and permanent

Tags: matrices, permanent

How to show that an $n \times n$ non-negative matrix $A$ is scalable $\textit{iff}$ perm($A$) $> 0$ ?

> Blockquote

Comment: What does "scalable" mean?

Comment: Definition 2.4 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.09669.pdf